# Why are these groups isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I have this group of permutations:

[image: permutations]

[image: permutes]

And I have this group of complex numbers:

[image: complex]

These groups are isomorphic to each other, but it seems I do not understand why.  I was looking for similarities in structure and I would have thought because they do not share the same structure, that they were not isomorphic.  Like take the diagonal of $g$s in the group of permutations.  In the group of complex numbers this same diagonal is made of different elements, $i$ and $1$.  It seems

I do not fully understand isomorphism, because I was looking for the same structure.  Could someone explain why these groups are isomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it by constructing an explicit bijective homomorphism.

$e\leftrightarrow 1$, $g\leftrightarrow -1$, and then $f\leftrightarrow i$ or $-i$ and $h$ is whatever remaining that isn't $f$.

---

Alternatively, you can show that both groups are cyclic of order four.

$i\mapsto i^2=-1\mapsto i^3=-i\mapsto i^4=1\mapsto i^5=i$

$f\mapsto f^2=g\mapsto f^3=h\mapsto f^4=e\mapsto f^5=f$

Comment: How did you construct the bijection though?

Comment: @TiernanWatson intuition / observation.  I recognized that the tables were exactly alike after some relabeling.  More specifically, I noticed that $e$ plays the role of the identity.  Next I noticed that $g^2=e$ which acts like $-1$ does in the other table.  The last choice could be either.

Comment: I can see that if you switch $i$ and $-1$ around you get the same structure that I was initially looking for.  I guess it is the uncertainty of accidentally missing it that I do not like because there is no straight method then like a formula to find a bijection.  I find working with permutations quite slow as well, so it would have taken me a bit more time to find the generator.

Comment: The identity should be easy to spot.  @TiernanWatson with experience and background knowledge, you will learn that there are only a certain number of possible structures for groups of a specific size.  Specifically, for groups of order four, there are only two possible.  Either isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4$ or isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$ (the [klein 4-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group)).  It is clear neither are the latter because the diagonal is not solely the identity.

Comment: Since neither can be the klein 4-group, they must both be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4$, and hence isomorphic to eachother.

Comment: Thank you for that.  So the method I used of re-arranging the order if which the elements were placed in was a good enough method to use in this problem?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* For the second group, use the order $1,i,-1,-i$.

Answer (score 1):

They are both isomorphic to they cyclic group of order 4, with $f$ as a generator of the first group, and $i$ a generator of the group of complex numbers.